# WP WooCommerce Webhook URL is not triggering in Live environment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I installed wordpress (with woocommerce) plugin in this location

```
subdomain.example.com
```

Then create a my php file for webhook in this location

```
example.com/webhook/file.php
```

I put this webhook url into webhook settings inside woocommerce with when order is created.

As I save the settings webhook was triggered because I'm creating a folder when ever someone creates order from front side of wordpress site.

This is the code inside my file.php

```
mkdir('foldername', 0777, true);
```

The issue is that when someone creates an order its not triggering the url, because if it was triggered then I will see the folder created by my code into my file location but its not exist. Its mean url was not hit(triggered) successfully.

The same thing is working fine in my localhost environment. I'm struggling this from several days and I'm unable to find the solution inside stackoverflow/google.

There is nothing critical in my woocommerce status;

```
PHP version okey 5.6
Latest wordpress version till current date.
Latest woocommerce plugin till current date.
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you guys!

Regards
Tahir

Comment: Make sure your server has enough permission to crate the folder.

Comment: As I mentioned that folder is creating if you hit save button or you put the URL directly inside web browser URL and hit ENTER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry guys, I have fixed the issue myself, my website has SSL and all my URLs are forcefully redirecting to https and I have putted the URL in webhook as non https, so my server were trying to move that URL and this way it was giving 302 Error.

Issue is now fixed after putting https in the webhook URL.

Thank you guys!